# Why would CToolBar::LoadToolBar fail?

Tags: c++, mfc, toolbar

I have been trying to add a toolbar to a dialog box and when I call m_ToolBar.LoadToolBar it fails.

I created a new toolbar resource and it's named IDR_TOOLBAR1, then I added this to the code

```
if(!m_ToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_FLAT, WS_CHILD | 
WS_VISIBLE | CBRS_TOP | CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | 
CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC) || !m_ToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_TOOLBAR1))
{
    EndDialog(IDCANCEL);
}
```

For some reason m_ToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_TOOLBAR1) returns false. I created the toolbar resource in Visual Studio so I think that my IDR_TOOLBAR1 is set up correctly.

What could be causing the load to fail?

edit: I'm not sure if this is related, but I noticed that the ID for the toolbar matches the ID for another control

```
#define IDC_EDIT_EVENTS                 213
#define IDR_TOOLBAR1                    213
```

was in the auto-generated resource file

edit2: When I tried to debug LoadToolBar I found that it calls MAKEINTRESOURCE which seems to be returning bad pointers. MAKEINTRESOURCE is just a bunch of casts though so I'm not sure what the issue is here.

Comment: I changed the ID in the resource.h file to an unused number and it's still returning false when I try to load it. 

As a side question, why would visual studio be generating ID's that are already used? I looked at the whole file and it seems to have done it several times previously as well.

Comment: The IDC_EDIT_EVENTS is a control ID which has nothing to do with resources. IDR_TOOLBAR1 is a resource identifier for two things: 1) a toolbar resource, and 2) a corresponding bitmap.  Step through the code for LoadToolBar() and find out whether it is failing to load the toolbar resource or the associated bitmap.

Comment: I am confused. I can load the debug symbols from the Microsoft server, but I am unable to actually "step into" the code.  The code itself is hidden by Microsoft and can only be viewed in assembly. Could you please tell me how you were able to step into the code?

Comment: Oh, I hate when that happens. It's a Visual Studio bug. To fix it, I do two things:

1) In the symbol locations(Tools - Options - Debugging - Symbols), I add a first entry of c:\windows\symbols (or equivalent if you have non-standard install)

2) Delete old symbol cache which is displayed as symbol path on same options page. If it is blank, try going to a command line shell and changing directory to %temp% and then doing a search for a directory that starts with Symbol or SymbolCache.  When you find it, delete the whole thing.

You might have to restart Visual Studio before/after deleting dir

Comment: That worked! Thanks :) It looks like the problem is that "#define MAKEINTRESOURCEW(i) ((LPWSTR)((ULONG_PTR)((WORD)(i))))" is returning a bad pointer and then the LoadToolBar function can't find the bitmap because the resource name is a bad pointer.

It's being passed 211 currently, which was set automatically when I made the toolbar. Is something wrong with how my resource ID's are being set?

Comment: Well, something screwed up. Just get your bitmap and toolbar id's to be the same and you should be good to go.

Comment: I believe that they are using the same ID, inside of my .rc file they both have the ID "IDR_TOOLBAR1"

Answer (score 0):

MAKEINTRESOURCE will return what appears to be a bad pointer, but this is normal. Resources can be strings or integers casted as strings.

Is this code by chance being compiled as a DLL?  If so, maybe you need to add the following code to the top of the function to allow MFC to figure out which DLL to get it from.

```
AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
```